# How to know pages or databases the user was allowed to access When authenticating with Notion OAuth

Tags: oauth, notion-api, notion

I am currently using the Notion API to create a lightweight Notion client.
When authenticating with OAuth, I assume the user can choose which Notion page to allow access to, but is there any way to know the result of this?

Comment: did you find the answer? I am also looking for it.